# svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy

Tags: svn, working-copy

On a server, I used the svn import command to put files into SVN.

I checked the files out to my local machine, made some changes and then committed back.

Now I want to update the server copy of the files, but using `svn update`, it shows "`skipped '.'`" and `svn status` shows "`svn: warning: '.' is not a working copy`".

Comment: How to make a directory 'working copy' ?

Comment: Are you running it in the folder that you've checked out to?  Is there a hidden .svn folder?

Comment: Hang on... are you running the update on the repository server? They should already have been updated when you did the commit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importing into svn doesn't make what you import a working copy. You have to check it out on the server just as you did locally. From then on it will be a working copy and you can use update.

Comment: makes sense, thanks. Now from zero, I want to put files from server to SVN (I did svn import, wrong way). How can do this ?

Comment: SVN Checkout is for getting a fresh copy of the server files to a local folder. Not for updating an existing version.

Comment: @Mark, there is no shortcut, there is no direct way to import and make it a working copy. Some IDE's like netbeans do this but underwater they still have todo an import export cycle. You have to import and then do a checkout. I allways backup and empty the orginal dir first thought i'm not sure that is actually needed. It might help to read the excellent manual: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to do an SVN Update first to merge and make a the directory a working copy. Then Commit to commit your changes. You can also sometimes use the SVN Cleanup command to resolve similar kinds of issues.

Comment: The OPs question stated that **svn update** didn't work, telling them to run it doesn't address the problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you enter

```
 svn update
```

and it says that is not a working copy, try looking at your path, look for a level up or down where you are (in the console use:

```
pwd
```

that will tell you where you are) and finally just double check that you are actually in a directory of the project, remember empty folders (structure ones) are not meant to be recognized, they just "draw" structures so paths can be more readables, so its basically that, the containing folder is not having files under source control

Your SVN directory is the one that has a folder (hidden) named as '.svn' take a quick look and corroborate you are on the right path

Answer (score 0):

1) Type in the command 'svn update'

2) Choose the option 'theirs-conflict' which will be the command 'tc'

Now you have a new copy of the file, so you can edit and do whatever you need to this file!