# pysvn gives error : Not a working copy

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I am trying to get the last modified author names for a set of files in svn.

I have the code checked out on my machine.

In my script, the absolute paths for all the files are read in a list. I am trying to extract the last edited author for each of the files using the following code.

```
for file in all_files:
    dir = os.path.dirname(file)
    entry = client.info(dir)
    print "Folder:"+dir+" And author:"+entry['commit_author']
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
File "test_main.py", line 110, in main
entry = client.info(dir)
pysvn._pysvn.ClientError: '.' is not a working copy
```

I tried giving the whole file name as argument for `client.info()` got the same result.

This might be a very simple issue but I am a newbie in python so not able to figure out.

EDIT:

I tried hard coding the folder path as:

```
  temp = "/home/gajananh/scripts/test/repo/test_proj/src";
  entry = client.info(temp)
  print "Folder:"+dir+" And author:"+entry['commit_author']
```

And it works !

In my first script when I just try to print `dir` variable in loop, it prints the correct paths. When I try to run `svn info` command on shell for the output, I get proper results.

I am not able to understand this mystery. Please help.

Comment: my guess is your problem is less about python and more about svn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869173/svn-warning-is-not-a-working-copy

Comment: @DrewV Please have a look at the edit. I don't think the problem is with SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I think `for file in all_files:` returns the files with relative paths like `./file.txt`

When you run `os.path.dirname(file)`, the path returned will be just a '.' (dot) which is given as argument to svn.

Try using full paths while calling the function.

Comment: all_files contains absolute paths. I have printed the variable dir and it is fine.

Comment: Try printing the output of os.path.dirname.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use info2.

```
path="http://svn/svn/foo/trunk/baz.c"
name_info_list = client.info2(path)
assert len(name_info_list) == 1

name, info = name_info_list[0]
for k, v in info.items():
    print "%s: %s" % (k, v)
```

http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_info2